# Search method by string value MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

A a part of my project i need to find a way to search my object by a string and show a result in view. Your help is appreciated.
in my `MainMedia` view i have a sidesection were i manually pass a string value to a `SearchMedia` method:

```
@section SideBar{
<ul>        
    <li> @Html.ActionLink("Astronomy", "SearchMedia", new {searchString = "Astronomy" })</li>
    <li> @Html.ActionLink("World", "SearchMedia", new { searchString = "World" })</li>
    <li> @Html.ActionLink("Movies", "SearchMedia", new { searchString = "Movies" })</li>
</ul>
}
```

This method should check every object if `TagsEnum` string and then display an object in `SearchMedia` view.

Here is my Media class

```
public class Media
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string body { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public string VideoLink { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public string tags { get; set; }
    public TagsEnum TagsEnum { get; set; }
}
```

TagsEnum Class

```
 public enum TagsEnum
    {
        [Display(Name = "Astronomy and space")]
        Astronomy,
        [Display(Name = "World around us")]
        World,
        [Display(Name = "Movies, video")]
        Movies
}
```

and finaly `MediaMainController` `SearchMedia` method

```
public ActionResult SearchMedia(string searchString)
{
    db.Medias.Where(i => i.TagsEnum.ToString() == searchString);
    return View(db.Medias.OrderBy(it => it.Title));
}
```

As i understand `.Where()` should find a match and return an object, however it is not working. How i can sort it out? Perhaps there are other ways to do it? Thank you

Update
I have changed it like this:

```
var result = db.Medias.Where(TagsEnum => TagsEnum.ToString() == searchString);
 return View(result.OrderBy(it => it.title));
```

but i still dont see the results to be sorted by search

**Update 2**
I have a class `MediaViewModel` which i use to create a list of objects, it looks like this:

```
 public class MediaViewModel
    {
        public List<Media> media { get; set; }
        public List<Video> video { get; set; }

    }
```

If i set up `SearchMedia` View like this

```
@model PhClub.Models.MediaViewModel
@foreach (var b in Model.media)
{}
```

i'm getting an error:
**The model item passed into the dictionary is of type System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereListIterator 1[PhClub.Models.Media], but this dictionary requires a model item of type PhClub.Models.MediaViewModel.**
If i set it up as

```
`@model IEnumerable<PhClub.Models.Media>
    @foreach (var b in Model)
    {}`
```

it is saying **Values of type 'Media' can not be converted to string.**
I think i need to change `SearchMedia` method to support `MediaView` class, but i didnt figure it out yet. Help is appreciated

Comment: "it is not working" is rarely a good problem statement. Are you getting no results, or an exception of some sort?

Comment: It is not sorting results, just showing every object as if search method didn't kick in

Comment: You aren't using the results of your where clause. In your return statement, you're just sorting the entire DbSet for the Media table. The answer by @sajeetharan corrects that.

Comment: Did you rebuild your project?

Comment: Trying, VS crashed and now i have some errors with ApplicationDbContext namespace... as soon as i sort it out ill give it a new try.

Comment: @maxb use  `i => i.TagsEnum.ToString()` as in the answer below

Comment: I'm getting an error when im trying to see result in SearchMedia view. It is saying Values of type 'Media' can not be converted to string. When im trying to loop through the list of objects.

Comment: @maxb can you show the view in which you are looping?

Comment: Plese check update to the question

Answer (score 2):

You should assign it to a variable and use it,

```
 var result = db.Medias.Where(i => i.TagsEnum.ToString() == searchString);
 return View(result.OrderBy(it => it.Title));
```

Comment: Do i understand right, that i need to change it like so: var result = db.Medias.Where(TagsEnum => TagsEnum.ToString() == searchString); as i dont have any i parameters in class? If so, i tryed it and it still not making search, as i still have all objects shown unsorted.