# Search by string in MVC 5 Part 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This is a follow up question which began [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43575140/search-method-by-string-value-mvc-5).

Quick recap of what is going on here. I'm trying to search list of objects by string value which i pass from hardcoded list of links looking like this:

```
@section SideBar{
<ul>        
    <li> @Html.ActionLink("Astronomy", "SearchMedia", new {searchString = "Astronomy" })</li>
    <li> @Html.ActionLink("World", "SearchMedia", new { searchString = "World" })</li>
    <li> @Html.ActionLink("Movies", "SearchMedia", new { searchString = "Movies" })</li>
</ul>
}
```

I pass it to `SearchMedia` method looking like this:

```
public ActionResult SearchMedia(string searchString)
        {
            var result = db.Medias.ToList().Where(i => i.TagsEnum.ToString() == searchString);

            return View(result);
        }
```

And trying to see a result in a `SearchMedia` View which i set up like this ( removed most of HTML code to be short and left only few lines):

```
@model IEnumerable<PhClub.Models.Media>
@foreach (var b in Model)
{ 
        <p>
            <h3> <a href=@Url.Action("Media", new { id = b.Id })>@b.title </a></h3>
            @b.description
        </p>
}
```

I created a several Media objects and pressing a link with existing TagsEnum value. After `SearchMedia` view is rendered i'm not getting any results at all. Blank page.  Would `.Where()` be the best and easiest way of doing it, or there are other options? Perhaps my whole approach is wrong, is it a common way of doing things like i do?
What do i miss here? Please help.

P.S. this is how my adress bar looks when i'm in `SearchMedia` view:

```
http://localhost:62220/Medias/SearchMedia?searchString=Astronomy
```

Comment: How is the TagsEnum defined?  Note that this is case sensitive.  If the enum is defined using only lower case letters, your comparison will not work.

Comment: it is shown in part one of the question, but here u go:  public enum TagsEnum
    {
        [Display(Name = "Astronomy and space")]
        Astronomy,
        [Display(Name = "World around us")]
        World,
        [Display(Name = "Movies, video")]
        Movies
}

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i figured it out. 
Whole approach is correct. Problem was where i didn't even thought it could be. I had my TagsEnum fields written in russian language, as i thought it should not make any difference, once searchword and parameter match to each other, turned out it does make a difference, once i changed searchword in English, it worked immediately. Thanks to everyone for your time and attention.